# Can't implement a timer when a key is released

Tags: c++, raylib

Recently, I've been making a 2d prototype-game using c++ and raylib as my graphics library, which has as its core mechanic that. when a movement key is released, e.g. "key_right", the player will continue moving for 3 more seconds, however, I can't make it work for some reason.

I believe my problem might have to do with pointers, therefore I have been doing more research on the topic, but I really can't seem to find what am I doing that is wrong. Here's my code:

## main.cpp

I have added some debugging standard print statements to try and find out what the problem is, but I really  can't figure it out.

```
#include <raylib.h>
#include "player.h"
#include "timer1.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 600;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Joj");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Player player(50, 50, 20, 20, YELLOW);
    GameTimer timer;
    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        std::cout << "Timer duration: " << timer.timerDuration << "\n";
        if (timer.timerDuration>0) std::cout << "Timer is on!";
        player.Movement();
        if (timer.runTimer)
        {
            timer.StartTimer(3);
            std::cout << "Timer is on?";
        }
        std::cout << "Timer value:" << timer.runTimer << "\n";
        timer.RunTimer();
            
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(GRAY);
        player.Draw();
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

## timer1.h

I'm aware I made attributes public, which should never be done and I know I should have used encapsulation, I was just trying to see if that might be the problem.

```
#pragma once
#include <raylib.h>

class GameTimer 
{
public:
    GameTimer();
    void StartTimer(float time);
    bool RunTimer();
    bool *prunTimer; 
    bool runTimer;
    float timerDuration;
    float* timerptr;
    int framesCounter;
private:

};
```

## timer1.cpp

The timer works with two methods, StartTimer() and RunTimer(). The first simply assigns the time parameter to a pointer pointing to the reference of the variable timerDuration, therefore altering it to the value of 'time', but that of and itself will not make the timer run, it will only set the value; that part is taken care of by the runTimer() method, which will deduct from the variable by the frame time in order to create a more or less consistent timer.

```
#include "timer1.h"
#include <iostream>

GameTimer::GameTimer() 
{
    prunTimer = &runTimer;
}

void GameTimer::StartTimer(float time) 
{
    timerptr = &timerDuration;
    *timerptr = time;
    *prunTimer = false;
}

bool GameTimer::RunTimer() 
{
    if (timerDuration>0) { *timerptr -= GetFrameTime(); return false; }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "timerDuration is less than or equal to 0" << "\n";
        return true;
    
    }
}
```

## player.h

I also have an entity class which contains basic methods for all entities, like Draw() and its Entity() constructor to define the properties of said object, but is not relevant in here.

```
#include "entity.h"

class Player : public Entity
{
public:
    using Entity::Entity;
    void Movement();
private:
    int leftMovement;
    int rightMovement;
};
```

## player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "timer1.h"
#include <iostream>

#define HSPEED 2
void Player::Movement()
{
    GameTimer timer;
    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) 
    {
        rightMovement = getPosX() + HSPEED; 
        setPosX(rightMovement);
    } else if (IsKeyReleased(KEY_RIGHT)) 
    {
        std::cout << "released!" << "\n";
        *timer.prunTimer = true;
        std::cout << "runTimer value: " << timer.runTimer << "\n";
    }
    
    if (timer.timerDuration>0) 
        {
            rightMovement = getPosX() + HSPEED; 
            setPosX(rightMovement);
        }
    std::cout << "Runtimer after: " << timer.runTimer;
}
```

Comment: You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Please refer to [How to make a timer?](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-make-a-timer) in the raylib FAQ.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning behind making `prunTimer` and `timerPtr` pointers? A timer should have three states: stopped (the default), running, and expired, and a `tick()` function to see when running should become expired. None of this requires pointers.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) */* [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The root cause of your trouble is that you have two definitions of `timer`: one in `main` and one that only survives for the duration of a single call to `Player::Movement`.

Answer (score -1):

Given the following `Timer` class: (exercise for you to implement)

```
class Timer {
  public:
    Timer(); // Create a timer that is not running.
    void Start(float duration);
    void Stop();
    bool IsRunning();
    bool Update(); // Did this update cause `duration` to be exceeded?
}
```

You can keep track of residual momentum as follows:

```
class Player {
...
    Vector2 momentum { 0, 0 };
    Timer momentumTimer;
...
}

const float HSPEED = 2 * 1000;

void Player::Movement() {
    bool timerExpired = momentumTimer.Update();
    Vector2 speed{0, 0};

    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) {
        speed += Vector2{HSPEED, 0};
        momentumTimer.Stop();
        momentum = speed;
    }
    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) {
        speed += Vector2{-HSPEED, 0};
        momentumTimer.Stop();
        momentum = speed;
    }

    if (IsKeyReleased(KEY_RIGHT) || IsKeyReleased(KEY_LEFT)) {
        momentumTimer.Start(3.f);
    }
    if (speed == Vector2{0, 0} && momentumTimer.IsRunning()) {
        speed = momentum;
    }
    UpdatePos(speed * GetFrameTime());
}
```

Note the use of `GetFrameTime` to make position updates independent of framerate.